# Change the Text of Label in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm new with swift and this is the Hello World! application for me.
I trying to change the text of Label when I press the button:

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var txbFullname: UILabel!

@IBAction func btnSubmit(sender: UIButton) {
    txbFullname.text = "hello"
}
```

}

I got the folloing error when I pressed the button in simulator :

[image]

Can you help please !

Xcode Version 8.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I recognize from your Screenshot, your button is not connected to the IBAction in the view controller, because the circle on the left side is not filled, thats the way you check if an outlet or an action is connected, see screenshot below:

[image]

Another way to check if your button is connected to the view controller (choose the Connections Inspector at the right side in the Utilities Area) in the storyboard, like in the screenshot below and see if its connected for example to the `Touch Up Inside` event:

[image]

If not, you need to connect your button, for example like in the gif below. `Ctrl + Drag` from your button to the view controller in the storyboard and then choose your btnSubmit function in the `Sent Events` section:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you help, I checked it and found it not connected.

Comment: Welcome, glad that I could help you!

Comment: Yes .. you did it :)

Answer (score 1):

The circle on your function left is hollow.this suggests that the function doesn't connect your button.that's the reason create the crash.
you need add the connect between the button and the function.
press `control` and drag your finger can fix this crash.

Comment: Thanks for you assist